# Is it possible to save the current URL of your browser in a txt/csv file?

Tags: java, python, selenium, url, webdriver

I want a script running in the back that saves the current URL of my webbroser, which i am manually navigating to websites, all the time. The usecase for my project is that I want to open a Google Maps location by hand and make the script in the background save the current URL in a csv or txt file to extract the coordinates of the URL as a string. (URL looks like that: https://www.google.de/maps/@48.2881292,9.3802822,13.58z) Is there a possibilty of doing this?

Comment: So you want to do it in java or python? do you have any code you have tried so far? isn't browser history good enough for storing visited links?

Comment: no matter if i do it with python or java i think. how does it work storing visited links ? sorry i am kind of new in coding and stuff. Thank you !

Comment: @Oliver Hnat Sorry I didnt see your answer until now. When Google is open, is it possible to navigate to google maps manually with mouse and keyboard ? Does python print out every time I change the direction then ? When it is, it's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Okay, in that case, why don't you just look into your browser history?

Comment: Because i need to do it automatically in my usecase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With python, you could get the url like this.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")

# do whatever you want to get to the right website

url = driver.current_url
print(url)

# Now you need to save the data

f=open("filename",'a')
f.write(url)
f.close()
```